# Parse Notifications for android (No GCM)

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

I have Tried using `Parse` `Push notifications` for android device, the `gcm` push through `Parse.com` works fine for me. But when i am trying to use `Parse.com` to send pushes directly to my app without gcm. Its not working for me. I have parse receiver in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. And application is getting installation object in data browser every time i install the application. Am I missing anything? And how does `Parse.com` actually sends pushes directly to our application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last got the answer to my question. I removed the `GCM` receiver but was still using permissions related to `GCM` receiver in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.
So after the removal of those permissions and only added the permissions and code related to `ParseReceiver` and `Parse.com` `push` works fine for me now.